# Is each metric continuum $\ell_p$-chain connected?

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, continuum-theory

This problem was motivated by the MO problems:
["Running most of the time in a connected set"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307534/running-most-of-the-time-in-a-connected-set), ["Is every metric continuum almost path connected?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308239/is-every-metric-continuum-almost-path-connected?rq=1) and ["Are $\varepsilon$-connected components dense?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308274/are-varepsilon-connected-components-dense).

Let $p$ be a positive real number. A metric space $(X,d)$ is called *$\ell_p$-chain connected* if for every points $x,y\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a sequence $C_0,\dots,C_n$ of connected subsets of $X$ of diameter $<\varepsilon$ such that $x\in C_0$, $y\in C_n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n d(C_{i-1},C_i)^p<\varepsilon$. Here $d(A,B)=\inf\{d(a,b):a\in A,\;b\in B\}$.

**Problem 1.** Is each connected compact subset of a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ $\ell_1$-chain connected? What is the answer for $n=2$?

**Remark 1.** By the method of the proof of Lemma from the answer to [this MO-problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307534/running-most-of-the-time-in-a-connected-set), it can be shown that each connected compact subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is $\ell_p$-chain connected for any $p>n-1$.

**Problem 3.** Is each connected compact metric space $\ell_1$-chain connected? $\ell_p$-connected for some $p$?

**Remark 2.** Each $\ell_1$-chain connected compact metric space is almost path connected in the sense of [this MO problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308239/is-every-metric-continuum-almost-path-connected?rq=1).

---

**Added in Edit.** It seems that the the answer of Anton Petrunin [to this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308239/is-every-metric-continuum-almost-path-connected) also yields a counterexample to Problem 3.

Comment: Taras, I like your $\ell_p$ problems (perhaps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308239/is-every-metric-continuum-almost-path-connected even more than this one; the connected subsets $C_k$ can be in practice simply 1-points sets--the continua can be this weird, as you know). Along your line, I have cruder notions (less metric, more combinatorial). And an exmaple too (I hope with a good probability :)). I feel that these combinatorial notions would provide a framework for your more subtle metric direction. Would you be iinterested? (It's hm-MO hence I tread carefully :-) ).

Comment: In addition to $\ell_p$-pth connectedness, you may also address a respective variation of Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem about continuous surjections.

Comment: @WlodAA Thank you for your interest in these questions. Of course the countinua can be singletons. In this case the $\ell_p$-connectedness became related to the Hausdorff dimension. It seems that each metric contiunuum of Hausdorff dimension $<p$ is $\ell_p$-connected.

Comment: @WlodAA Concerning the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz Theorem this indeed can be done (as soon as we prove that each continuum is $\ell_1$-chain connected). Here we have two options: either each metric continuum is $\ell_1$-chain connected and this will be a great result, or there are contniua, which are not $\ell_1$-chain connected. This case is even more interesting since such continua will have non-trivial $\ell_1$-chain connected components and the space of such components has a natural metric. So, we can iterate this construction, obtain some ordinal ranks etc. This will lead to an interesting theory

Comment: Some 40y+ someone asked the following: is every compact metric space a countable union of subsets such that the sum of squares of the diameters of these subsets is $\ \le\ 1\,?$

Comment: Taras, I'll write to t.o..., thank you. One of the critical examples is solenoid, say the simplest one. It may illustrates the involved issues well.

Comment: @WlodAA The solenoid is not weird enough: its path components are dense, so it is $\ell_p$-chain conneceted for every $p>0$ (with just one jump).

Comment: @WlodAA Concerning the question of 40+ old, it is immediately related to the Hausdorff dimension (more precisely, if it is $\le 2$).

Comment: Taras, thank you for your expert comments-answers. (I still feel that solenoid is interesting in the given context in a wide sense; it's just subtle :) ).

Comment: I'm confused regarding remark 1. The lemma in your answer seems to imply that every planar continuum is $\ell^1$-chain connected. And also you say there that the proof of the lemma doesn't generalize to higher dimensions but here you say that it does.

Comment: @JamesHanson Remark 1 says the lemma only partly generalizes to $\ell_{p}$-chain connectedness for all $p>n-1$, but it is far from the desired $\ell_1$-chain connectedness. In fact, we do not even know if each continuum in $\mathbb R^3$ is $\ell_2$-chain connected.